# Railstutorial : which parts of the app to upgrade first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

After finishing with Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, which parts of the sample app proposed in tutorial should I upgrade first? Authentication method comes to mind first..

Given the huge popularity of that tutorial, I suppose there is something like a list of steps to be taken for that app to become more up-to-date in this ever changing world of web dev etc. etc. etc.

Overall is it a good idea to use that app as a foundation for building something more advanced?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned Rails with that book :)
However, even the authentication algorithm used there is great to learn, in practice you can use other alternatives. For example I use the wonderful [Devise](http://rubygems.org/gems/devise) gem (Railscasts [209](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) and [210](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise)).

There are some ideas at the end of the book that explain how you can extend the application. However, I think that building your own app from scratch is better now that you know how to do it.

After reading that book, I created some basic projects, and in parallel started reading [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) and [The Rails 3 Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321445619).

Hope it helps! Welcome to the Rails world :)